# Split large texts into chunks in separate rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table, where some texts are atrociously big. I want to make sure every row in the query output does not exceed, say, 100.000 characters. How do I do that?

Here is a quick sample:

```
WITH large_texts AS (
  (SELECT 'humongous text goes here' AS text ,'1' AS id)
  UNION ALL 
  (SELECT 'small one' AS text ,'2' AS id)
  UNION ALL
  (SELECT 'and another big one over here' AS text ,'3' AS id)
)

SELECT * FROM large_texts
```

Let's say I want output `text` column to be less than 10 characters. So, I need this result:

```
+----+------------+
| id | text       |
+----+------------+
| 1  | humongous  |
+----+------------+
| 1  | text goes  |
+----+------------+
| 1  | here       |
+----+------------+
| 2  | small one  |
+----+------------+
| 3  | and anothe |
+----+------------+
| 3  | r big one  |
+----+------------+
| 3  | over here  |
+----+------------+
```

It would be even better if I could also avoid splitting in the middle of words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It would be even better if I could also avoid splitting in the middle of words.

Consider below approach

```
create temp function split_with_limit(text STRING, len FLOAT64)
returns ARRAY<STRING>
language js AS r"""
    let input = text.trim().split(' ');
    let [index, output] = [0, []]
    output[index] = '';
    input.forEach(word => {
        let temp = `${output[index]} ${word}`.trim()
        if (temp.length < len) {
            output[index] = temp;
        } else {
            index++;
            output[index] = word;
        }
    })
    return output
""";
select id, small_chunk
from yourtable_with_large_texts, 
unnest(split_with_limit(text, 10)) small_chunk with offset
order by id, offset
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: no way! You can do this?! I've been using GBQ for years and didn't know that I can run a piece of javascript right in a query! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use the `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL` function specifying the number of characters as a pattern:

```
SELECT id, chunk
FROM large_texts
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(text, '.{1,10}')) AS chunk;
```

Comment: BigQuery does not support these types of CTE

Comment: Sorry @SergeyGeron, my mistake.

Comment: Getting "Cannot parse regular expression: invalid repetition size" when setting the range to anything beyond `'.{1,1000}'`.

Comment: Yes, you are right @stkvtflw, I don't know why (I couldn't find anything about it).

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to split word by word, then try this:

```
WITH large_texts AS (
  (SELECT 'humongous text goes here' AS text ,'1' AS id)
  UNION ALL 
  (SELECT 'small one' AS text ,'2' AS id)
  UNION ALL
  (SELECT 'and another big one over here' AS text ,'3' AS id)
)

SELECT  id, newtext FROM large_texts
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(split(text,' ')) AS newtext;
```

The result will look like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input , but this is not helpful .

Comment: I checked quite a lot, it is weird that BigQuery cannot support splitting into chunks of a specific size... Sorry, I hope some better answer will come along

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
with cte2 as
(
    SELECT 'humongous text goes here' AS text ,'1' AS id
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'small one' AS text ,'2' AS id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'and another big one over here' AS text ,'3' AS id
)
, cte3 as 
(
select id,text ,generate_array(0,length(text),10) arr
from  cte2
),
cte4 as
(
select *
from cte3,unnest (arr) as idx with offset  as rn
)
select id,substr(text,idx + 1,10)
from cte4
```

***output***
[image]